# Microsoft SQL between statement for characters is not inclusive?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to select all values that have a first name beginning with the letters a-d, however when I do this

```
select * from tblprofile where firstname between 'a' and 'd'
```

I get all values from a to c, not including d, how can I make sure it includes d?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is inclusive.

You don't get the results you want because any string beginning with 'd' and longer than 1 character is greater than 'd'. For example `'da' > 'd'`.
So, your query would return all values starting with 'a', 'b', 'c', and a value 'd'.

To get the results you want use

```
select * from tblprofile where firstname >= 'a' and firstname < 'e'
```

Comment: Or `select * from tblprofile where firstname like '[a-d]%'` would also do the trick (if the OP is on a case insensitive collation)

Comment: Ended up using the regex [a-d]%, so thanks Martin, however also the rest of you guys explained why it was not working correctly previously! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try using Left() Function:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblprofile
WHERE LEFT(FirstName,1) between 'a' and 'd'
```

Comment: Using a function in a `where` clause like that will ignore indexes.

Comment: Thanks Jakub. I agree your answer is a lot more elegant. Out of curiosity, what would the impact of ignoring indexes be?

Comment: It would need to read the whole table instead of just being able to seek into just those names matching the condition. In this case likely would need to read 6 or 7 times as many rows assuming names are equally distributed across the alphabet.

Comment: So as a rule of thumb I should, whenever possible, shy away from using functions within a where clause?

Comment: Yes. They usually make the expression unsargable.

Comment: Just googled sargable. Wasn't aware that using functions on WHERE, ORDER, GROUP BY and HAVING clauses could result in such a performance issue. Top tip, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using a union select like this

SELECT * FROM tblprofile WHERE LEFT(FirstName,1) = 'a'
union 
SELECT * FROM tblprofile WHERE LEFT(FirstName,1) = 'b'
union
SELECT * FROM tblprofile WHERE LEFT(FirstName,1) = 'c'
union
SELECT * FROM tblprofile WHERE LEFT(FirstName,1) = 'z'

The advantage of using union is if you need to get the results stating with A, K and X, strings out of sequence.